# Terraform unsupported attribute error using Scaleway

Tags: terraform, provisioning

After I run `terraform apply` and type 'yes' I get the following error 3 times (since I have 3 null resources):
`Error: Unsupported attribute: This value does not have any attributes.`
I checked each of my entries in my connection block and it seems to be coming from the `host` attribute. I believe the error is because ips.address is only generated after the server has launched while terraform wants a value for host before the BareMetal server has been deployed. Is there something wrong I'm doing here, either I'm using the wrong value (I've tried ips.id also) or I need to create some sort of output for when ips.address has been generated and then check host. I haven't been able to find any resources on BareMetal provisioning in ScaleWay. Here is my code with `instance_number = 3`.

```
provider "scaleway" {
  access_key      = var.ACCESS_KEY
  secret_key      = var.SECRET_KEY
  organization_id = var.ORGANIZATION_ID
  zone            = "fr-par-2"
  region          = "fr-par"
}

resource "scaleway_account_ssh_key" "main" {
    name       = "main"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}


resource "scaleway_baremetal_server" "base" {
  count = var.instance_number
  name = "${var.env_name}-BareMetal-${count.index}"

  offer  = var.baremetal_type
  os = var.baremetal_image
  ssh_key_ids = [scaleway_account_ssh_key.main.id]

  tags = [ "BareMetal-${count.index}" ] 
}



resource "null_resource" "ssh" {
  count = var.instance_number
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    user = "root"
    password = ""
    host = scaleway_baremetal_server.base[count.index].ips.address
    port = 22
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    script = "provision/install_java_python.sh"

  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a null resource for a provisioner. A provisioner can be directly inside the real resource (the baremetal server). See https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html.

Comment: I previously tried that and it did not work, using ```host = self.ips.address``` gives a cycling error between the 3 BareMetal resources.

Comment: `ips` is a list, you need to pick one, see terraform documentation. Also, when throubleshooting, the simpler the better. Try removing the `count` everywhere and bring up one. Then reintroduce the count.

Comment: ```ips``` is a list but ```ips.address``` is a string...